# Cannot Specify Foreign Key Tables When Adding New Foreign Keys

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms

I'm trying to use the Relationships dialog in SQL 2008 to add a new foreign key to a table field.  When I go to add one, I am not able to change and specify the Foreign Key Base table or any others in the "Tables and Columns Specification" area...they're all greyed out for those values and uneditable and I"m not sure why.

Comment: Are you able to do joins using the pk & fk's? or do queries fail when you try to do joins?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have you clicked the ellipsis button to get the wee dialog box?

The section "Tables and Columns Specification" area has a wee button where you choose the tables and columns: you can't enter stuff directly.

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH for calling my attention to that wee button!

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is too visual for me.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable 
  ADD myNewColumn int NOT NULL
go

 ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable
   ADD CONSTRAINT FK1_MyTable FOREIGN KEY(myNewColum) REFERENCES dbo.myRefTable(ID)
go
```

If you try this "the thing" may come-up with some kind of an error that describes where the problem is.

Comment: I like visual.  Why code when you can do things like this to tables visually.

Comment: SQL is already painful enough.  I love staying away from it as much as possible...

Answer (score 0):

Easier is to add a database diagram, add the desired tables, then drag/drop the relations from and to the intended fields. In this way a logic name of the relation will also be created.